# Log Twig errors on strict_variables in Symfony

Tags: twig, symfony

In Symfony, Twig is configured with `strict_variables` to `false` in production mode.

However those errors are not logged in Monolog. Is there a way to make Twig log `strict_variables` errors?

Comment: Maybe you can implement a Kernel listener that listens to twig errors? That would require twig to fire events though..